# Dagger - Dependency inject into Activity

Tags: kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have a main activity as below:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {

  @Inject
  lateinit var configuration: Configuration

  ...
}
```

And a module defined like:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class AppModules {

 @Singleton

 @Provides
    fun bindDeviceConfig(): Configuration {
        return Configuration()
    }
}
```

When I try running this it gives an error:

lateinit property configuration has not been initialized

I've looked at the documentation and can't seem to get my head around why I'm getting this issue. Does anyone know why?

Comment: You are trying to inject object type Configuration but your bindDeviceConfig function returns DeviceConfig, types must match

Comment: @YunusDilber Apologies, I copied the wrong method, updated!

Comment: Do you have your application configured?